# how to implement SAML sso using Java, Java EE

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am newbie to SAML 2.0. I was unable to find a book on `SAML` on amazon which will guide you how to get started with `SAML`, especially `SAML2.0`.

What I am looking for an end to end `SSO` demo app development using `SAML` and an Identity Provider (Open Source), so that I can simulate end to `SSO`. So what I mean by that is, generate a token from Identity provider, process SAML message/send response back etc and then create 2 or more domain/logins to simulate `SSO` with success or error message.

Any tutorial/book/resource you know for novice to intermediate or advance on `SSO` with `SAML` will be appreciated.

Lastly how to use `SAML` in `WS-Security`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point you might want to have a look at this page from CAS wiki: https://wiki.jasig.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6063484

or this page from Google: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation